# Hash mapping riddle

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how do I convert this:

```
{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
 "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"},
 "3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"},
 "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}}
```

into this:

```
{"album1"=>
  {"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
   "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"}},
 "album2"=>
  {"3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"},
   "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}}}
```

in the most efficient way.

The first is the format that iTunes stores track information. The last is the format I'd need to process tracks at the level of 'album'. I've been staring at this all day and, not being very good at Ruby, have conceded defeat. Thank you for the tutorial on hash kung-foo.

---

**EDIT**

While I was waiting for the moderator to decide if this was OK, I got a solution:

```
album_tracks = {}
titles = []
tracks_hash.each do |album_id, album_hash|
  titles << album_hash["album"] if !titles.include? album_hash["album"]
end

titles.each do |title|
  tracks = {}
  tracks_hash.each do |album_id, album_hash|
    tracks[album_id] = album_hash if title == album_hash["album"]
  end
  albums_hash[title] = tracks
end
```

I'm guessing there is a more efficient strategy involving some sort of mapping that doesn't require passing over the entire hash twice?

Answer (score 2):

Your output can be achieved through a pretty straight-forward call to `group_by`, followed by a few transforms to turn the results back into hashes:

```
albums = {"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
          "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"},
          "3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"},
          "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}}

albums.group_by { |k,v| v['album'] }.map { |k,v| [k, v.to_h] }.to_h

# => {
#  "album1"=> {
#    "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
#    "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"}
#   },
#  "album2"=>{
#    "3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"},
#    "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}
#  }
#}
```

The key is understanding which methods are available on `Enumerable` for translating one structure into another (ie `group_by` and `map`) and then knowing that Ruby lets you freely transform arrays to hashes and vice versa.

The first, call, `albums.group_by { |k,v| v['album'] }`, produces the correct *outer* Hash structure, but the values have the form `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...]`. Ruby will let you turn that same structure back into a `{key1: value1, key2: value2}` hash using `to_h`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I was looking for a better way to do this and from a readability standpoint this is by far the best. The best I could do is increase the performance a bit using `#tap` e.g. `albums.group_by{ |_,v| v['album']}.tap{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| h[k] = v.to_h} }` but it definitely makes it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
album_tracks = tracks_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(album_id, album_hash), album_tracks|
  album_tracks[album_hash['album']] ||= {}
  album_tracks[album_hash['album']][album_id] = album_hash
end
```

Comment: FYI: You can use `Hash.new` with a block to specify an initializer for producing default values. The first line of your block could then be eliminated: `albums.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k] = {}}) { |(id, album),hash| hash[album['album']][id] = album }`

Comment: Ah nice to know, thanks! I have initialized hashes with default values (such as 0) but never went the extra mile.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
h = { "1"=>{ "id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1" },
      "2"=>{ "id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2" },
      "3"=>{ "id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1" },
      "4"=>{ "id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2" } }

h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
  g.update(v["album"]=>{ k=>v}) { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
end
  #=> {"album1"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
  #               "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"}},
  #    "album2"=>{"3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"},
  #               "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}}}
```

Note that `update`'s argument,

```
v["album"]=>{ k=>v}
```

is shorthand for the hash

```
{ v["album"]=>{ k=>v} }
```

The steps:

```
enum = h.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
  #                  "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"},
  #                  "3"=>{"id"=>3, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track1"}, 
  #                  "4"=>{"id"=>4, "album"=>"album2", "track"=>"track2"}}:
  #                  each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned using decomposition:

```
 (k,v),g = enum.next
   #=> [["1", {"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"}], {}] 
 k #=> "1" 
 v #=> {"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"}
 g #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed:

```
 g.update(v["album"]=>{ k=>v }) { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
   #=> {}.update("album1"=>{ "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"})
   #      { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
   #=> {"album1"=>{ "1"=>{ "id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"}}}
```

The two hashes being merged, `{}` and

```
{ "album1"=>{ "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"} }
```

have no keys in common, so the block is not used to for calculating any values.

The next element of `enum` is then passed to the block:

```
(k,v),g = enum.next
  #=> [["2", {"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"}], {}]
k #=> "2" 
v #=> {"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"} 
g #=> {"album1"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"}}}
```

The update calculation is now

```
g.update(v["album"]=>{ k=>v }) { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
  #=> g.update("album1"=>{ "2"=> {"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"})
```

The hash we are building,

```
 g #=> { "album1"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1" } } }
```

and the hash being merged,

```
 { "album1"=>{ "2"=> {"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"} } }
```

both have the key `"album1"`, so the block is employed for determining the value for that key:

In the block

```
 { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
```

we have

```
 o #=> { "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1" } }
 n #=> { "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2" } }
```

so

```
 { "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"} }.
   update({ "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"} })
   #=> { "1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1" },
   #     "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"} }
```

The hash `g` is now

```
g #=> {"album1"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track1"},
  #               "2"=>{"id"=>2, "album"=>"album1", "track"=>"track2"}}}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.